# loop throught data in DSN connection

Tags: asp.net, odbc, recordset

I set Netsuite (our business management program) up for web service and ODBC connection.
I configure the ODBC in my server to connect to their web service via system DSN and file DSN. I tested the connection with user id and password and it worked.
But now in my VS2013 my ASP.net (VB) page,  I can't get to loop through  the records in any table:

```
Dim cn As OdbcConnection
cn = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER=CData ODBC Driver for NetSuite 2015;dsn=odbc1;uid=myemail.com;pwd=mypassword")
cn.Open()

Dim cmdstring33 As String = "select * from CustomList"
Dim cmd33 As New OdbcCommand(cmdstring33, cn)
Dim rds33 = cmd33.ExecuteReader
'While rds33.Read
'    Response.Write(rds33("Internalid"))
'End While
cn.Close()
```

But i get the following error:
 ERROR [HY000] An account must be specified in order to login to NetSuite.
in "Dim rds33 = cmd33.ExecuteReader"
But the account works when I test the connection in ODBC administration window

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

With the ODBC .NET Managed Provider, you should either specify the DSN you wish to use:

```
cn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=odbc1")
```

OR you should specify the ODBC Driver and the connection string:

```
cn = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER=CData ODBC Driver for NetSuite 2015;accountid=...;password=*****;roleid=3;user=...;version=2013_1")
```

where you fill in the connection string values based on the documentation provided for the Driver.

*Note that our Drivers (CData software) don't require user/password by default, so you don't need to specify the `uid` or `password` when using a DSN.

Comment: Hi Jerod,  I updated my connection. but still getting a same error,
I am using CData for connection to ODBC. and strange thing is in ODBC config  when I test the connection it is saying Connection was successful.
and I can look at the all the tables in netsuite.  any ideas?   Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the change(s) you've made?

Comment: I changed my connection sting to :
"DRIVER=CData ODBC Driver for NetSuite 2015;accountid=...;password=*****;roleid=3;user=...;version=2013_1
but still getting the same error:
ERROR [HY000] An account must be specified in order to login to NetSuite

Comment: It appears that there's a problem with the connection string. Can you reach out to our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) for more help? That way we don't clog SO with a conversation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that